# Can read() return value exceed the count value?

Tags: linux, c, read

With the below function signature

`ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`

While I do understand based off the man page that on a success case, return value can be lesser than *count*, but can the return value exceed *count* at any instance?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A call to [`read()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) might result in more data being read behind the scenes than was requested (*e.g.* to read a full block from storage, or read ahead the following blocks), but `read()` itself *never* returns more data than was requested (`count`). If it did, the consequence could well be a buffer overflow since `buf` is often sized for only `count` bytes.

POSIX (see the link above) specifies this limit explicitly:

> Upon successful completion, where *nbyte* is greater than 0, *read()* shall mark for update the last data access timestamp of the file, and shall return the number of bytes read. **This number shall never be greater than *nbyte*.**

[The Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) isn’t quite as explicit, but it does say

> `read()` attempts to read **up to *count* bytes** from file descriptor *fd*
> into the buffer starting at *buf*.

(Emphasis added.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that in case of error read() will return -1 and if you treat that as unsigned it will almost certainly be larger than count.

Comment: The question is explicit about only dealing with the case of a successful call to `read()`, not one that fails.

Comment: If you treat `ssize_t` as unsigned you’re going to run into all sorts of problems, not just considering that the `read()` result is larger than `count`...

Comment: Isn't that the whole reason that the return type is `ssize_t` rather than `size_t`? It's specifically a signed type so that `-1` is included. Why would you cast it to an unsigned type before checking for the error?